# Member of a CBV in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm, trying to implement a LoginRequiredMixin. For example, if user goes to /post/6 and he isn't logged in, he is redirected to /auth/login/?next=/post/6. I'm trying to make a function that will redirect user either to /post/* (according to next in the url) or to the / if there is no next in the url. I tried to get a url param in GET request, save it to CBV member and then use it in post. But for some reasons it isn't actually saved. Here is a piece of my code:

```
class LoginView(View):
    redirect_to = ''

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['login'], password=request.POST['password'])
        print(self.redirect_to) # It's equal to '' here

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        else:
            print("Account doesn't exists!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:index'))


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.redirect_to = 'edited'

        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'authorization/login.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

Maybe there is any other solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is *designed* not to work, and you shouldn't try. Requests are stateless. User-specific information must be stored in the db or the session.

Comment: Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a `login` view that handles the `next` GET parameter. You should use this instead of writing your own.

Comment: @Alasdair i will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your safest bet is to use [`braces`](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/):

### Installation

```
$ pip install braces
```

### Usage

The [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#loginrequiredmixin) pretty much aims to replicate the `login_required` decorator functionality for CBVs:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class SomeSecretView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "path/to/template.html"
    login_url = "/login/"

    def get(self, request):
        return self.render_to_response({})
```